# What is the main difference between QT 4.8.7 and QT 5.15.2 regarding to GLEW and OpenGL code?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I work under the big QT project like OpenGL developer, so, i'm not clearly understand the problems, just trying to investigate them.
When project was worked under QT 4.8.7 version their legacy OpenGL code was compiled and worked correctly(We use GLEW to initialize OpenGL functions and have our own opengl wrapper classes, like framebuffers and OpenGL context). After migration to QT 5.15.2 we got this error:

```
/*
from File1.h
from File2.h
from File3.h
from qt_generated/File4.cpp:10:
*/
error: #error gl.h included before glew.h
 #error gl.h included before glew.h
```

I understand that without code nobody can helps me, so, I just want to know the approaches to resolving such type of problems, what should I pay attention to first?
I tried to play with order of including files.

Comment: Pretty much that. Make sure your custom OpenGL header stuff is included before you include any Qt stuff. Or just migrate it all to use Qt's OpenGL handling.

Comment: @Botje where I can read the difference regarding to topic of the question? Just I need to proof, that QT really has a lot of changes

Comment: 4.8.7 was released in 2011, 5.15.2 in 2020. nine years, one major and 15 minor releases is a lot of time for changes. I'm not sure why you need to prove that there were a lot of changes or who is asking for it..

Comment: @Botje Just maybe there is solution to migrate legacy opengl code without huge changes

Comment: Yes, the solution is to reorder your includes... Or just removing the error from glew.

Comment: Presumably Qt included it somewhere to do its analogue of GLEW's getprocaddress dance. Since your legacy code still uses the GLEW header it will refer to the pointers imported by GLEW.

Comment: @Botje so i need to include it before QT libraries?